# Define an element to require a parent element in PECL BBCode

Tags: php, dom, bbcode, pecl

I have the following rules defined for allowing a user to create tables via bbcode:

```
        'table' => array(
            'type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
            'open_tag' => '<table>',
            'close_tag' => '</table>',
            'childs' => 'tr',
        'tr' => array(
            'type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
            'open_tag' => '<tr>',
            'close_tag' => '</tr>',
            'childs' => 'th,td',
            'parent' => 'table'),
        'th' => array(
            'type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
            'open_tag' => '<th>',
            'close_tag' => '</th>',
            'parent' => 'tr'),
        'td' => array(
            'type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
            'open_tag' => '<td>',
            'close_tag' => '</td>',
            'parent' => 'tr'),
```

The idea is, you can define a table, a table row, or table cells, but:

- a `TABLE` can only have `TR` as its children
- a `TR` can only have a `TABLE` as its parent, and can only have `TH` or `TD` as its children
- a `TH` or `TD` can only have a `TR` as its parent

This parent/childs directive is documented *very* briefly here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php

However, basic experimentation shows that the "parent" directive does not seem to do anything. That is to say, with the above rules, it will happily parse a `TR` element at the top level. This seems like a very strange design decision, so I wonder if I am doing something wrong? Further, since the forum that this is implemented on is laid out in a table, when someone does that it breaks the forum display rather spectacularly.

Comment: I don't know the BBCode parser, but what do you want to happen if a `tr` is used without a `table`? If removing the whole block is appropriate, maybe run the output of this through HTMLPurifier, which I guess would regard it as invalid HTML.

Comment: What is supposed to happen is that the [tr] remains a literal [tr] in the string. I've found I can sort of work around the issue by declaring a top-level element and explicitly blacklisting [tr] and [td] as children, but this doesn't fully solve the problem either since you can just put them inside any other tag.

Comment: The only way I can think of to directly work around this issue is to explicitly blacklist tr and td from *every* tag, but I'm loath to do so when there is clearly a "correct" way to whitelist elems